# Changing default compiler from clang to gnu gcc in termux

Tags: linux, gcc, terminal

I want to set default compiler from `clang` to `gcc` in termux (android application).

gcc isn't available in official repo so I used pointless community repo. But now I can't configure the termux to use gcc instead of clang.
usr/bin/ contain g++, gcc, gcc-8, g++8.
But `gcc --version` command shows default clang.
`gcc-8 --version` shows:

```
"CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "gcc-8" : library "libc++_shared.so" not found 
linker: CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE "gcc-8": library "libc++_shared.so" not found.
```

Comment: Are you trying to compile something, or this error just shows from `gcc-8 --version`? Could you try `ldconfig -p | grep "++"` and tell us if you see "libc++_shared" in there?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well. The question that is asked by @Andy J is unfortunately less than helpful because there is not even ldconfig in this environment and I saw on Reddit that one of the developers said it's not even needed. (I doubt they are correct but it's not needed to fix this problem.

Do:

```bash
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$PREFIX/lib
export PATH=$PATH:$PREFIX/lib
```

Then finally you should be able to use GCC version 8.0.

```
~/gccbuild $ gcc-8 --version                                                       gcc-8 (GCC) 8.3.0                                       
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

This is free software; see the source for 
copying conditions.  There is NO         
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or F
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Personally I'm trying to install it so that I can compile GCC 12, wish me luck with that lol.

Comment: any luck with gcc?